# Redeclaring Type of Instance Variable

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible to do something like the following?

```
UILabel *welcome;

if (someFlag == 1)
  welcome = myTextfield // somehow reset to a textfield, not a label
else
  welcome = myLabel;

...use welcome variable...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the type of a variable as your code is written.  You could however declare at as `id` which allows you to store any NSObject (or subclass thereof) pointer:

```
id welcome;

if (someFlag == 1)
  welcome = myTextfield // somehow reset to a textfield, not a label
else
  welcome = myLabel;
```

or you could use UIView, since that is the parent class of both controls:

```
UIView *welcome;

if (someFlag == 1)
  welcome = myTextfield // somehow reset to a textfield, not a label
else
  welcome = myLabel;
```

but otherwise no, you cannot redeclare the type of a variable without making a new variable.